# Not enough Storage is available to process this command when running java utilities from command line

Tags: java, windows, coldfusion, cmd

I'm on Windows Vista 64 bit, with a 64 bit jvm installed. I'm trying to use jstack and jmap -- two utilities that come with the JDK -- to peek into an application server's guts. This works fine on a windows xp machine, 32 bit.

However, when I run these commands against the processid for a ColdFusion application server on this vista64 machine, I get the error message in the title of this post.

All I'm doing is running jstack , where pid is the processid of my CF server, and I'm getting this

this machine has plenty of available memory, but I highly doubt it's a memory problem. The reason I say that is that if I start JBoss, which is taking up just as much memory as CF, I can run jstack against that process.

Thanks for advice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out. The problem was that ColdFusion was running as a windows service. By stopping the service and running from the command line (jrun start cfusion) , I was able to successfully use the JDK tools

Answer (score 4):

this posting provides details on how to execute jstack when the process is running as a windows service.  basically, use the psexec command.

[Jstack and Not enough storage is available to process this command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906620/jstack-and-not-enough-storage-is-available-to-process-this-command)