# java jstack tool insufficient memory or insufficient privilege to attach

Tags: java, memory, jstack, privilege

I am really confused about:
    In my windows 2008r2, I have a windows service, in fact it's a java progress running as **SYSTEM** user. Now, I use **Jstack** rawly to the the service. But it occur error :

```
 insufficient memory or insufficient privilege to attach
```

But if I use Jstack's options **-F** , it can work finely. I view the jdk's source, It uses a class **BugSpotAgent** to finish above.

I want to know the root cause I can't use **Jstack** rawly, is it the **SYSTEM** user privilege problem? I also have try to use **PsExec.exe**(a tool) to run my **Jstack** rawly(That means I will use **SYSTEM** user to run **Jstack**), but it still can't work.

Can you help me?

Thanks & Regards!

Comment: See also [Jstack and Not enough storage is available to process this command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906620/jstack-and-not-enough-storage-is-available-to-process-this-command) for workaround for windows services.

Answer (score 5):

*jstack* can only latch on to a process started by **Same User** in **Same Session**. When a session is not specified the *psexec* command latches on to console session and throws this error while trying to get thread dump.

The **solution** is to ensure the user and session used with *psexec* is the same as one used for target java process.

if it has been started by a regular user, 
   a. use the same user credentials to login without -s or -h flag
   b. find the session ID in which the process was started. (You can find it using Task Manager and going to the Tab Users). Use this session id with the flag -i

`psexec \\server-name -u username -p password -i session-id command`

e.g.

`psexec \\192.168.1.1 -u john -p pass123 -i 1 jstack.exe 4242`

*Note: If the java process has been started by a SYSTEM user use the flag -s*