# "Insufficient memory or insufficient privileges to attach " when capture the tomcat dump

Tags: java, debugging, tomcat, coredump

I tried to capture the tomcat process dump with jmap , however I got the error " Insufficient memory or insufficient privileges to attach" , obviously there is enough memory, and the currently login user is in the role local administrator group. If I run the cmd command as administrator, it still failed.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin>jmap.exe -dump:format=b,file=d:\temp\HeapD
ump.hprof 30452
30452: Insufficient memory or insufficient privileges to attach
The -F option can be used when the target process is not responding
```

Comment: Have you tried using the -F option?
Are you running jmap as the same user as Tomcat?

Comment: I see that error before in tomcat. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149635/java-jstack-tool-insufficient-memory-or-insufficient-privilege-to-attach

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jstack and Not enough storage is available to process this command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906620/jstack-and-not-enough-storage-is-available-to-process-this-command)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar scenario where we were running a jetty server wrapped as a windows service and I wanted to take a memory dump of it. I think most of the answers elsewhere on SO deals with situations where the process you want to take a dump of is not running as a windows service. This [link](https://community.appdynamics.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/What-to-do-when-Windows-user-can-t-capture-heap-dump-using-jmap/ta-p/24170) helped.

Download [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) and run jmap like this:

`<path to psexec>PsExec.exe -s "C:\Program Files\Java\jd
k1.8.0_131\bin\jmap.exe" -dump:file=<filename> <processid>`