# Thread dump for a Citrix virtualized process?

Tags: java, citrix, jvisualvm, thread-dump, jstack

I need to do a thread dump to a JAVA application running through Citrix XenApp (on Windows 2008).

I'm able to see the process in Task Manager, but when I'm trying to do the thread dump using `jstack -l <PID>` I'm receiving the following error: `"Not enough storage is available to process this command"`.

When I'm using the `JVisualVM` tool, I'm not seeing the running process.

The process is seen in the tools above when running the application directly from the server (Windows 2008).

Is there a working method to gather the thread dump?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906620/jstack-and-not-enough-storage-is-available-to-process-this-command

Comment: I've already tried all of the suggestions in that thread.
`psexec -s` gives the same error message and the other suggestions are irrelevant to Citrix XenApp.