# jstack output - get tid for java Thread.getId

Tags: java, multithreading, jconsole, jstack

I had a look at existing questions on getting the thread id like [java-thread-id-and-stack-trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222108/getting-the-java-thread-id-and-stack-trace-of-run-away-java-thread) .

But I'm not able to figure out something that seemed simple. I want to make a JSP tool to stop a thread in Java.

I know it's a bad idea in general but we need it as  we can't use JConsole in our environment cause some hardening of JBoss.

My questions are, take a sample jstack output:

1. `Event Batch Processing (Spring UAA/1.0.2)" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000041e27800 nid=0x363b waiting on condition [0x00007f9a89267000]`
   From this which id would be the `thread.getId()` as defined in `java.lang.Thread`? What is the last token in this line `[0x00007f9a89267000]`?
2. How do I convert (Java code would be super) the `hex` to a Java `long`?
3. Could you tell me why this did not work -> I took a hex `tid=` from a jstack of a thread that was hung in a never ending loop. I then did this:

   ```
   Thread thrd = null;
   String thrdId =request.getParameter("thrd");
   if(thrdId != null){
       out.print("thread " + thrdId + " :");
       out.flush();
       Map<Thread,StackTraceElement[]> map = Thread.getAllStackTraces();
       Set tt = map.keySet();
       Iterator<Thread> ti = tt.iterator();
       try{
           long idFind = Long.parseLong(thrdId);
           out.print("<br> idFind thread |" + idFind + "| <br>");
           boolean found = false;
           while(ti.hasNext() ){
               thrd = ti.next();
               if(thrd.getId() == idFind){
                   out.print("<br> stopping thread " + thrd + " <br>");
                   out.flush();
                   thrd.stop();
                   out.print("<br>stopped " );
                   found = true;
                   break;
               }
           }
           if(!found){
               out.print("<br>not found " );

           }
       }catch(Exception e){
           out.println("<br>err " + e + "<br>");
       }

   }
   ```

Output of this was not found. The input param was the tid - pasted in Windows 7 calc, Programmer mode (hex) and then clicked Dec.

**UPDATE:**

In my test code when I made a JSP that loops infinitely, outputting a char every few 10000s iterations - then did a jstack, got:

```
"http-0.0.0.0-8181-4" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000000d4eb000 nid=0x2f58 waiting on condition [0x0000000010fee000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)

...(stack trace)
at org.apache.jsp.t.testing.loop_jsp._jspService(loop_jsp.java
...more stack trace...
```

I ran jstack a few times and get this entry every time.

But when I run my JSP with thread `id = 000000000d4eb000`, it cant find it, since the app container names threads uniquely I was able to find the thread and when I print:

```
out.print("" + cnt + " \"" + thrd.getName() + "\"| id :" + thrd.getId() + "| hex :" +  Long.toHexString(thrd.getId()) + "| <br>");
```

I get :

```
93 "http-0.0.0.0-8181-4"| id :1389| hex :56d| 

93 is the thread number in my internal counter in the loop.
```

So what jstack apparently identifies as finds as `0x000000000d4eb000` internal JVM knows as
`1389 hex :56d`? Finally changed the JSP to search by name and stop the thread. lucky the thread names are all different. But is this a bug - running Windows, JBoss 4.2, Java 1.6 update 32?

Comment: `i then did this:`  It would help if we could see what you did.

Comment: Sorry just formatted the question and added back the code. my No Script was blocking the editor controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only find and stop your own threads. I would try interrupting the thread in case it can stop gracefully.

Stopping a thread is a bad idea in general as it can leave the application in an inconsistent or unrecoverable state.  The only way you can avoid this is to have a very good understand of exactly everything the thread might be doing, in what case its likely that fixing the code so it stops gracefully is simpler and better

> we cant use jconsole in our environment

jvisualvm is a much better tool in any case. I wouldn't use jconsole unles syou had to.

> how do I convert (java code would be super) the hex to a java long?

```
long idFind = Long.parseLong(thrdId, 16);
```

> could you tell me why this did not work

Either you didn't run this from the same process or the thread caught the `ThreadDeath` error you triggered.

Comment: its a servlet so a thread started by my app container (jboss); i can see the thread name in jstack. are your saying that Thread.getAllStackTraces();
wont return all threads started by jboss.     `Thread.getAllStackTraces();`
 is called in a jsp in the same jboss?

Comment: I would expect it to return all the same threads.  I suggest you print out all the thread's names and ids in hex to see if you can see a match.

Comment: Thanks Peter I tried what you suggested, put results in the main question - marked "UPDATE" . Not sure why but the tid returned by jconsole does not match what I get from `Thread.getAllStackTraces()`