# Get stack trace unique number

Tags: java

Is there a way to assign unique id for every Java stack trace which appears after some exception? I would like to to get the number and use it for faster troubleshoot.

Comment: What about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222108/getting-the-java-thread-id-and-stack-trace-of-run-away-java-thread

Comment: Not clear what you are looking for. Would some kind of hash value suffice?

Comment: @Henry yes, unique hash value which will be printed for every error stack into the log will be enough

Comment: You would need to do some experiments, but it should not be too hard to write a hash function that hashes the information which is important for you.

Comment: For faster 'trouble shooting' you are pursuing the wrong solution, use a  logging framework to report the program state along with file and line numbers. e.g. log4j.

Comment: You could just maintain a counter, catch every exception and repack it to a custom exception with the current counter value and the original exception attached. Then increase the counter.

Comment: Please select my answer as correct if it solves your question, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just create a custom Exception and hash the stacktrace and set it as a unique id?

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.exception.ExceptionUtils;

public class MyException extends Exception {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2145930259049207199L;

    private final int uniqueId;

    public MyException(String message) {
        super(message);
        this.uniqueId = ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(this).hashCode();
    }

    public int getUniqueId() {
        return uniqueId;
    }

}
```

If you want a truly unique id for each message (i.e. you're not trying to track duplicate exeption message), you can just set uniqueId in the constructor accordingly intead:

```
this.uniqueId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Comment: Do note though: hashCodes are not unique, and different hash codes can (and will for longer strings) collide with each other.

Comment: Very true, however I'm guessing that's what he wants (to track duplicate exceptions occurring).  If he wants one unique, then he could just set uniqueId = UUID.randomUUID().toString()

Comment: Note that this solution uses the **Apache** library, its not plain Java.